# Open Word document in workflow

Tags: workflow, designer

I have created a 2010 workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 which creates a Word document in a Document Library. This functionality works as desired. I would like the workflow to also open the Word document once the document has been created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open it for display? No. Workflows are asynchronous and do not directly interact with the user or the user interface. A workflow can add an item to a task list or send an email to give the user a link to the document.

Comment: Thanks Mike, much appreciated. I figured that was likely the case, but it's good to have it confirmed. I will most likely setup an email with a link to the document instead.